# Switch audio output not working

Tags: audio, hdmi, omxplayer, output

I'm using Raspbian Stretch Desktop for my Raspberry Pi 3B.

I'm using a VGA screen with an HDMI to VGA adapter, so I want the jack to work as my main audio output. If I unplug the HDMI and reboot, the speakers work as intended, but whenever I plug it, they stop working because the audio output is sent through the HDMI.

What I want is to force the audio output to be through the jack.
Since doing it from `sudo raspi-config` menu didn't work, I tried what lots of people in lots of forums say, and I used this command:

```
amixer -c 0 cset numid=3 1
```

But it doesn't work for me (I tried with every posible number combination, just in case). I also uninstalled pulseaudio because someone said it may be a workaround to the problem, but it didn't work either.

Notice: I rebooted the RPi a lot of times while trying this.

Does anyone have any idea of what the problem is and how can I solve it?

.

**SOLUTION**:

The problem was with omxplayer. It seems to ignore the configuration and use its own. Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Raspbian, Run

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Navigate to `7 Advanced Options` => `A4 Audio` => `Force 3.5mm ('headphone') jack`, save and reboot.

Comment: This was the first thing I tried... Forgot to mention it. Thanks anyway.